# Is there a way to make sure css does not change when calling .print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I recently added some javascript code to my web page that would automatically print the page. The code looks something like this as you might guess:

```
<script>
    window.print();
</script>
```

However, this for some reason changes the layout/css of the web page.

For example, this:[image]

Will change to this:

[image]

I under stand that I could make a print sheet, however, I would prefer to keep the current look if possible.

Also, as an added note, the window.print() function does not change the layout itself, even when going from the original and manually clicking print, the same result occurs.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? Perhaps it contains a `print` media query?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS, however there is nothing that I've added in Angular for printing. Perhaps, I should try that instead?